# How to know if DeferWindowPos() caused reallocation?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

Lets say I have the following code for resizing a tab control inside a window:

```
HDWP hDWP = BeginDeferWindowPos(5);
HDWP hDWPUpdated = DeferWindowPos(hDWP,
                                  hWinParent,
                                  hTabControl,
                                  nullptr,
                                  0,
                                  0,
                                  newTabSize.cx,
                                  newTabSize.cy,
                                  SWP_NOZORDER
                                  );
```

It is possible that `DeferWindowPos` caused an increase in the underlying structure size, for example if there are more pages than initially indicated. In this case, `hDWPUpdated` will be a handle to the updated position structure. Is there a way to detect this structure size update? I was thinking of comparing `hDWP` and `hDWPUpdated`:

```
if(hDWPUpdated != hDWP)
{
    // Reallocation took place...
}
```

but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632681(v=vs.85).aspx) only states that:

> [...] The handle returned by this function may differ from the handle passed
>   to the function.

which leads me to think that even though the the structure size might not have changed, the handles might not be the same. Can I assume if the handles are not the same, then sizes are different? If not, how could I do this?

Comment: *Is there a way to detect this structure size update?* -- For what reason would this information be useful to your application? -- *Can I assume if the handles are not the same, then sizes are different?* -- If it's not documented, then you can't assume this.

Comment: If you ask `BeginDeferWindowPos()` to allocate a structure for 5 windows, and then call `DeferWindowPos()` for 1-5 windows, I think it stands to reason that the structure won't have to be reallocated, and `DeferWindowPos()` will likely just return the same structure handle it is given (but that is not guaranteed). It would reallocate when you call it for 6+ windows. So, why not just keep track of how many windows you ask to move? Or better, why not call `BeginDeferWindowPos()` with an accurate window count to begin with?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It could be used to assert if `BeginDeferWindowPos()` is not called with an adequate window count.

Comment: `DeferWindowPos` will succeed even if `BeginDeferWindowPos` was called with an inadequate count, so why would you want to assert? If you can't predict ahead of time exactly how many windows will be moved, don't worry about it. P.S. the whole point of a handle is that you're not allowed to know anything about the structure it represents.

Comment: @MarkRansom The idea is to catch those possible inadequate counts. In these cases, `DeferWindowPos` succeeds but is less efficient because of the reallocation. If code using this function ever gets modified in a way the count becomes inadequate (possibly by some developer which has no deep knowledge of `DeferWindowPos`), I want the assertion to notify the developer so that he can take a look and hopefully fix it.

Comment: I fail to see a bug that needs fixing. Resizing the underlying structure is cheap in comparison to repositioning windows, invalidating and repainting them. Plus the call into the kernel. Those are the expensive calls. If you need to optimize, go there first.

Answer (score 2):

A handle is designed to hide all implementation details. You can't compare the contents of the structure behind the handle, nor can you infer anything when the handle changes.

The one thing you *can* do is track the number of calls to `DeferWindowPos` yourself. I question whether it's worth it, since `DeferWindowPos` is designed to work whether you predicted the number of windows being moved or not. Any efficiency aspect seems likely to be lost in the noise. But if you insist, my suggestion is to create a class that tracks it all for you and provides a little RAII.

```
class CDefer
{
    int m_nRemaining;
    HDWP m_hDWP;
public:
    CDefer(int nMaxDefers) : m_nRemaining(nMaxDefers)
    {
        m_hDWP = BeginDeferWindowPos(nMaxDefers);
    }
    ~CDefer()
    {
        EndDeferWindowPos(m_hDWP);
    }
    void DeferWindowPos(HWND hWnd, HWND hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, UINT uFlags)
    {
        m_hDWP = ::DeferWindowPos(m_hDWP, hWnd, hWndInsertAfter, x, y, cx, cy, uFlags);
        ASSERT(m_nRemaining > 0);
        --m_nRemaining;
    }
};
```

Comment: I like the idea, of providing some RAII for this, but I don't get how this implementation helps my case. If I instanciate this with `nMaxDefer = 5` but I end up having 6 windows, how will this help me? There will be one `reallocating` call to `DeferWindowPos` (or it will fail if ressources are lacking) and `m_nRemaining` will drop to `5`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BobMorane you're missing the `ASSERT`.  It will trigger if you've called `DeferWindowPos` too many times.

Comment: But when the `ASSERT` will pop, the reallocation (within `DeferWindowPos`) will have taken place. If the developper does not call `DeferWindowPos` too many times, the reallocation will have gone by undetected.

It is my understanding from the documentation that `DeferWindowPos`, if given an insufficient window count at the beginning, will (silently) reallocate and return the handle, but not necessarly be called again.

Comment: @BobMorane the assertion fires when `DeferWindowPos` has been called too many times, allowing the developer to go back and fix the count that was passed to `BeginDeferWindowPos`. That was your goal, wasn't it? I don't understand your obsession with reallocation.

Comment: @BobMorane If you are worried about the reallocation, then do some profiling. I bet `DeferWindowPos` won't be the bottleneck. Also you could have a fallback that calls `SetWindowPos` if `DeferWindowPos` fails.